# Looping (ω) Combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Can someone explain this combinator? I understand $\lambda x. x$,
but I don't understand $\lambda x. x x$
From what I've gathered, this means *given x, return the application of x to x*. I don't understand the *application of x to itself* part. For example, given $x = 2 + y$, would
$\lambda x. x x$ result in $y^2 + 4y + 2$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2 + y is a number, not a lambda calculus term so you cannot use that here.

you can apply it to the identity and it will reduce like this:

$$(\lambda x. x x) (\lambda y. y) \to (\lambda y. y)(\lambda y. y) \to (\lambda y. y)$$

> rewritten in terms of combinators this is:  $\omega I \to II \to I$

notice what happens if you apply it to itself?

$$(\lambda x. x x) (\lambda x. x x) \to (\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x) \to \ldots$$

> rewritten in terms of combinators this is:  $\omega \omega \to \omega \omega \to \ldots$

it reduces to itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! That was an great explanation of what I was misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you mean "you can apply it to the identity"?

Comment: @joriki, corrected. Thanks.